# Why is character padding is less when followed by string

Tags: c++, class, variables, padding, member

As per my knowledge in 64 bit operating system ,while reading class variables, to reduce CPU cycles  c++ compilers does padding and try to fit the data in chunks of 8 bytes.Now in below program , since int i & j will take up one 8 bytes and can be read without extra CPU cycle,  should the character 'name 'not be padded by 7 bytes so that string will be read smoothly in 3 cycles of 8 bytes . if so sizeof(e1) should return 40.But it is returning only 36.Why so? note:If I follow the character by double which takes 8bytes then the character is being padded by 7bytes the sizeof e1 is returned as 24. and my Operating system is 64bits.

```
#include <iostream>

     using namespace std;

     class emp{

        public:
          int i;            //needs 4 bytes
          int j;            //needs 4 bytes
          char name;        //should be padded by 7 bytes
          string s;         //needs 24 bytes
         //double d;        //needs 8 bytes.
    };

    int main()
    {
     emp e1;
     cout<<sizeof(e1);
    }
```

//the answer should be 40 but i'm getting 36.`

Comment: Printing out the value returned by the alignof() operator for each member-variable is a good quick way to check that your ideas about each item’s alignment requirements coincide with the compiler’s.

Comment: In your question, you state that you are using a 64-bit operating system. However, when compiling, are you also creating a 64-bit executable? Or are you maybe creating a 32-bit executable? Which compiler are you using and how exactly are you compiling the program?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes I checked it is creating 64bit exec.

Comment: I don't remember reading anywhere that the order of members in memory layout should be same as declaration. I once eventually shot myself in the foot trying to access a member of an unaligned instance of a structure, using the offset calculated from an aligned object. It was an outdated tool-chain though. Compiler can change placement of subobjects depending on the alignment. The other - more sane - possibility is CPU reading words at exactly half alignment in expense of more read cycles. Optimization for speed vs memory can change this behavior.

Comment: Please add the line `cout<<'\n'<<(void*)&e1.i<<'\n'<<(void*)&e1.j<<'\n'<<(void*)&e1.name<<'\n'<<(void*)&e1.s<<'\n';` to your program, so that we can see the exact addresses of the member variables. Note that in C++, I believe it is better coding style to use `reinterpret_cast` instead of C-style casts. I only used C-style casts because they are shorter.

Comment: I have checked three major 64-bit compilers. Two of them have `sizeof(std::string) == 32` and the third one has `sizeof(e1) == 40`. If you are using one of those you may have one or more errors in your problem description. You may want to provide more details about your OS, compiler, and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Through my debugging I found that your "Char name" is taking memory of 4 bit .
38

The reason behind above behavior is data structure alignment and padding. Basically if you are creating a 4 byte variable e.g. int, it will be aligned to a four byte boundary i.e. it will start from an address in memory, which is multiple of 4. Same applies to other data types. 2 byte short should start from even memory address and so on.

Hence if you have a 1 byte character declared before the int (assume 4 byte here), there will be 3 free bytes left in between. The common term used for them is 'padded'.

THis is I found from somewhere, I think this will help you to understand..